Frage über Adverbien als Hauptsatzkonnektoren
Ich bin dabei, einige Sachen zu wiederholen.  Ich lese im Moment  über Adverbien, die als Hauptsatzkonnektoren benutzt werden können.  Das Buch sagt, diese Adverbien können auf „Position 1" des zweiten Hauptsatzs gehen, z.B.

Ich müsste Arbeiten, trotzdem werde ich ins Schwimmbad gehen.

Gerade danach kommt aber das Folgende:

Diese Hauptsatzkonnerktoren sind Adverbien und können auch auf
Position 3 oder auch weiter hinten im Satz auf der Position, die ihrer
Bedeutung entspricht, stehen...Es regnet, ich gehe trotzdem ins
Schwimmbad.  Es regnet, ich gehe nach der Arbeit trotzdem ins
Schwimmbad. Sie müssen aber immer nach den Pronomen stehen: Es
regnet, ich kaufe mir trotzdem ein Eis

(Hervorhebung von mir)
Meine Frage ist, ob „Sie müssen aber immer nach den Pronomen stehen" bedeutet, dass die als Konnektoren benutzen Adverbien immer nach den Pronomen stehen müssen, oder nur dann, wenn sie nicht auf Position 1 stehen.  D.h., wäre Folgendes richtig?

Es regnet, trotzdem kaufe ich mir ein Eis.

Ich glaube schon, aber ich finde das, was das Buch sagt, ein bisschen unklar.

Der fragliche Absatz behandelt den Fall, dass der Konnektor auf Position 3 oder weiter hinten im Satz steht. Dies gilt für alle Aussagen im Absatz, auch für "Sie müssen aber immer nach den Pronomen stehen." Der Fall, dass der Konnektor auf Position 1 steht, wurde ja schon vorher behandelt.
Der Satz ist Es regnet, trotzdem kaufe ich mir ein Eis. ist folglich korrekt.
Inkorrekt wäre dagegen ein Satz wie Es regnet, ich kaufe trotzdem mir ein Eis. oder Es regnet, ich kaufe trotzdem ein Eis mir.

Das relevante inkorrekte Beispiel wäre wohl  "Es regnet, aber ein Eis kaufe trotzdem ich mir". Der Punkt ist, dass die unbetonten Pronomen sofort nach Position 2 kommen müssen, es ist eine Regel über Pronomen, es hat nicht speziell mit Adverbien etwas zu tun.

@Alazon stimmt, ich habe die Antwort entsprechend geändert.

Was wäre denn mit: "Er ist viel netter als sie, ich kaufe trotzdem ihr ein Eis" [statt ihm]? Oder "Er hat viel mehr Geld als ich, ein Eis kaufe trotzdem ich ihr" [statt er]?
